# Smallest composite number in array

Tags: c++

I am totally new to programming and I am bit stuck on my code. I wrote code where I wanted to find smallest composite number in array(using only low-level arrays). When I wrote down like size of array 3 and enter 1 2 77, than it throws out random 16. Can you explain why is this happening and perhaps give some solution how to fix this.

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int fun(int n)
{

    int arr[n];
    int mini = arr[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cin >> arr[i];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 2; j < arr[i]; j++)
        {
            if (arr[i] % j == 0)
            {
                if (mini > arr[i])
                {
                    mini = arr[i];
                }
                else
                {
                    mini = mini;
                }

                break;
            }

        }

    }

    return mini;
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    cout << "Size of array: ";
    cin >> n;

    cout << "Write " << n << " numbers: " << fun(n) << endl;

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: `mini = mini;` is suspect. Self assignment doesn't accomplish much.

Comment: The real problem is `mini=arr[0]` before assigning the contents of `arr`.

Comment: Take care with `int arr[n];` 1) it's not valid in Standard C++ for a number of reasons, looming large in these reasons is 2) this is a great way to allow the user to run the program out of Automatic storage. The user can specify a number like 1,000,000 and voop!  Program starts exhibiting mystery behaviour.

Comment: *using only low-level arrays* -- `int arr[n[` is not low-level, and it isn't even C++.  Second, even if you did use "high-level" arrays (maybe you mean `std::vector`), the code you would come up with would be almost identical to the same code if you used regular arrays.  Just because someone uses `vector` doesn't mean the program will magically write itself.

Comment: [Variable length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) are not part of the C++ standard. Even in the language C they are now (since [C11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_(C_standard_revision))) an optional feature, i.e. C11-compliant C compilers are no longer required to implement that feature.